# Reactjs - filtering the data from api response

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working on reactjs project, pretty new on this technology. I have an api data response which differentiate between the products i.e. Internally products (that are uploaded from the application) and external products (that are crawled from other websites). For more clarity , the json response of the api looks like below.

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "TestProductForAzure",
        "description": null,
        "owner": "Seeded Company",
        "url": "http://localhost:54729/api/product/3",
        "type": "Internal",
        "rank": 0,
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "OAS",
        "description": null,
        "owner": null,
        "url": "https://support.example.com/en-ae",
        "type": "External",
        "rank": 0,
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "OAS",
        "description": null,
        "owner": null,
        "url": "https://support.example.com/en-al",
        "type": "External",
        "rank": 0,
    }
```

As you can see the object `type` is the one which is helping me differentiating between all the products in the api response. 
I want to put a filter on it as when the user selects from a dropdown Internal it will only show internal products and if user selects External it will only show external products.

What I have tried till now is below.

**SearchActions**

```
import {
  SEARCH_PRODUCTS,
  FETCH_PRODUCTS,
  LOADING,
  PAGINATE,
  KEYWORD
} from "./types";
import axios from "axios";
import { results } from "./data/result";
import { store } from "../_helpers/store";
import { userService } from "../_services";

import { apiBaseUrl } from "../config.example";

const token = userService.getToken();

export const searchProduct = text => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: SEARCH_PRODUCTS,
    payload: text
  });
};

export const fetchProducts = text => dispatch => {
  console.log("Called from ", text);

  const api = `/Search?searchString=${text}`;

  axios
    .get(apiBaseUrl + api, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })

    .then(res => {
      console.log("hello", api);
      try {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_PRODUCTS,
          payload: res
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error", err);
      }
    });
};

export const saveKeyword = text => dispatch => {
  const api = `/search/${text}`;

  axios
    .get(apiBaseUrl + api, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Keyword Api called");
      try {
        dispatch({
          type: KEYWORD,
          payload: res
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error in Keyword", err);
      }
    });
};

export const paginate = currentPage => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: PAGINATE,
    payload: currentPage
  });
  dispatch(fetchProducts("paginate"));
};

export const setLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: LOADING
  };
};
```

**Searchbar.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  searchProduct,
  fetchProducts,
  setLoading,
  saveKeyword
} from "../../../_actions/search.action";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  handleInputChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.searchProduct(e.target.value);
  };

  onClick = e => {
    console.log("I am " + this.props.text);
    console.log("Search button clicked");
    this.props.saveKeyword(this.props.text);
    this.props.fetchProducts(this.props.text);
    // this.props.setLoading();
  };

  render() {
    const { text, loading } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="s130">
        <form
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
          }}
        >
          <div className="inner-form">
            <div className="input-field first-wrap">
              <div className="svg-wrapper">
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="auto"
                  height="auto"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                >
                  <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z">
                    {" "}
                  </path>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <input
                id="search"
                type="text"
                value={text}
                placeholder="What are you looking for?"
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                ref={input => (this.textInput = input)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="input-field second-wrap">
              <Link to={`/dashboard/search?q=${text}`}>
                <button
                  className="btn-search"
                  type="button"
                  onClick={this.onClick}
                >
                  {" "}
                  SEARCH{" "}
                </button>
              </Link>
            </div>

            {loading ? "Searching" : ""}

            {this.pr}
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  text: state.product.text,
  loading: state.product.loading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  searchProduct,
  fetchProducts,
  setLoading,
  saveKeyword
})(SearchBar);
```

**Search-results-container.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import queryString from "query-string";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SearchResult from "./search-results";
import { results } from "../../../_actions/data/result";
import Select from "react-select";
import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";
import SearchBar from "./search-bar";
import { fetchProducts, searchProduct } from "../../../_actions/search.action";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

class SearchResultContainer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).q;
    console.log("Location Props", this.props.location.search);

    this.props.searchProduct(query);
    this.props.fetchProducts(query);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("nextProps", nextProps);
    // if (nextProps.query !== this.props.query) {
    //   this.setState({ query: nextProps.query });
    //   return this.searchRepositories(nextProps.query);
    // }
  }

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.props;
    const str = this.props.location.search;
    const res = str.split("?q=");
    console.log("PROS", this.props);

    const companies = [
      {
        label: "Internal",
        value: "Internal"
      },
      {
        label: "External",
        value: "External"
    ];

    return loading ? (
      <div class="row"></div>
    ) : (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-2" />
          <div className="col-sm-8">
            <div class="container bootstrap snippet">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                      <h2>We are Fetching:{res}</h2>
                      <small>
                        Request time (5-10 seconds): Please be patient, this may
                        take sometime, as we are gathering information
                      </small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <SearchBar />
//For Internal and External

           <Select options={Select}></Select>

            <br></br>
            <div class="row">
              <Loader
                type="ThreeDots"
                color="#00BFFF"
                height="100"
                width="100"
                timeout={2500}
              ></Loader>
              <SearchResult />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-2" />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.product.loading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { searchProduct, fetchProducts })(
  SearchResultContainer
);
```

**search-results.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SingleSearchResult from "./single-search-result";
import { results } from "../../../_actions/data/result";

import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { paginate } from "../../../_actions/search.action";

import Pagination from "./pagination";
import "./test.css";

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  // onChangePage = data => {
  //   this.setState({
  //     pageLimit: data.pageLimit,
  //     totalPages: data.totalPages,
  //     currentPage: data.page,
  //     startIndex: data.startIndex,
  //     endIndex: data.endIndex
  //   });
  // };

  render() {
    const { products, pagination, paginate } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {products.map(result => (
          <SingleSearchResult result={result} />
        ))}

        {/* <Pagination
                  totalRecords={products.length}
                  pageLimit={pageLimit || 2}
                  initialPage={1}
                  pagesToShow={5}
                  onChangePage={this.onChangePage}
                /> */}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="center-block">
            <Pagination
              resultsPerPage={pagination.pageLimit}
              totalResults={10}
              paginate={paginate}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  products: state.product.products,
  pagination: state.product.pagination
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { paginate })(SearchResults);
```

and the last where my all search results appear looks like this

**singlesearchresult**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Rating from "./rating";
import "./test.css";
import { Spinner, Collapse, Card, CardBody } from "reactstrap";
import { detailsProduct } from "../../../_actions/product.details.action";
import { ProductDetails, DoctorProductLocation } from "../../../locations";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { setLoading } from "../../../_actions/search.action";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";
import Select from "react-select";
import { GoThumbsdown, GoThumbsup } from "react-icons/go";
import Footer from "../footer";

// import { fetchProducts } from "../../../_actions/search.action";
// import { detailsProduct } from "../../../_actions/product.details.action";

function onClickHandler(id) {
  console.log("calling Details Product", id);
  detailsProduct(id);
}

export default function SingleSearchResult(props) {
  // console.log("PROPS FROM SINGLE SEARCH", props);
  let result = props.result;

  //Collapse For External
  const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setCollapse(!collapse);

  const loading = () => <Spinner color="success" />;

  // console.log("SINGLE SEARCH PROPS RESULT", result);
  // loading = () => <Spinner color="success" />;
  {
    /* <Loader
            type="ThreeDots"npm
            color="#00BFFF"
            height="100"
            width="100"
            timeout={1000}
          ></Loader> */
  }
  console.log("Length", result.title.slice(0, 3));

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="s130">
        {/* <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 col-sm-12 col-md-7"> */}
        <div className="col-lg">
          <div className="container">
            <div className=""></div>
            {/* Loader Here ibox-content*/}
            {result.type === "Internal" ? (
              <Link
                value={result.productid}
                to={DoctorProductLocation.path}
                onClick={() => onClickHandler(result.productid)}
                //onClickHandler(result.productid)
              >
                <h3 style={{ color: "#1a0dab" }}>
                  {result.title}
                  <hr></hr>
                </h3>
              </Link>
            ) : (
              //Try With OnClick Function
              <a onClick={toggle} target="_blank">
                <h3 style={{ color: "RED" }}>
                  {result.title}
                  <hr></hr>
                </h3>
              </a>
            )}
            <p className="p1">{result.description}</p>
            {/* //href={result.url} */}
            {/* {result.type == "Article" ? <p>by {result.author}</p> : ""} */}
            {/* <Rating rating={result.rating} /> */}
          </div>

          {/* <a
          href={result.url}
          target={result.url === "External" ? "_blank" : ""}
          // data-toggle="modal"
          // data-target="#aripiprazol"
        >
          {" "}
          <cite class="iUh30">{result.url}</cite>
          <br />
        </a> */}
          {result.type === "Internal" ? (
            <Link
              className="iUh30"
              to={DoctorProductLocation.path}
              onClick={() => onClickHandler(result.productid)}
            >
              {/* <a className="iUh30">{result.url}</a> */}
              {/* <p>DDH PRODUCT</p> */}
            </Link>
          ) : (
            //Try With OnClick Function
            <Collapse isOpen={collapse}>
              <Card style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
                <CardBody>
                  Source:
                  <a className="iUh30" href={result.url} target="_blank">
                    <a>{result.url}</a>
                  </a>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
              <Card style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
                <CardBody>
                  <a
                    href={result.url + "subscribe"}
                    style={{ color: "#1a0dab" }}
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    Subscribe
                  </a>
                  <p>{result.description} </p>
                </CardBody>
                <div className="row">
                  <GoThumbsup className="col-6"></GoThumbsup>
                  <GoThumbsdown className="col-6"></GoThumbsdown>
                </div>
              </Card>

              <br></br>
            </Collapse>
          )}

          {/* RANKING */}
          {/* <p className="rank">Visited {result.rank} times</p> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see above in **search-result-container.jsx**, I was trying to use react-select library for the dropdown and then for the response but I do not have any idea that How can I pursue it.

Comment: That is way too much code for such a question.. Use the array method called filter()

Comment: @TasosBu I put the code so if you want understand what is happening in all over the code.